# How to model product part selection with restrictive rules?

Tags: database-design

I need to model database for product configurator where the user first selects a product template and adds features into that template. Available features need to be validated so that only features that fit previous choices are available for selection.

Example:
 
 1. User chooses "Car Model 1"
 
 2. We list available engine models
    based on "Car Model 1".

So far model for database is still manageable because it's hierarchical, we'll use some kind of dependency table:

```
ParentID  | ChildId
- - -- - - - - - -- 
<Car1>.id  | <Engine1.id>
<Car1>.id  | <Engine2.id>
```

Now the question is, how can I model all the cases where a certain choice restricts some hierarchically "same level" features? For example we would like to implement following logic:

- "Car Model 1 can include Headlight1,Headlight2 or Headlight3"
- "If you include Engine1 (in Car Model 1), you can't include Headlight2."

There is not a top-down dependency between Engine and Headlights. It's only an exception to the rule.